# How to redirect to a page and add custom headers to the redirect

Tags: jquery, html, zend-framework2

Hi i need to build a log in page with out using sessions or cookies.

How do i do a redirect and add custom headers the the redirect?
I want to add a custom header "Authorize" to the redirect so i can validate that the token is a logged in user.

I'm using Zend-framework and Jquery. Also in not allowed to use meta tags.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you going to add this header to headers sent by user to server?

Comment: It seems what you wish for is not possible as the added custom headers get discarded because the redirect is considered as a new request by the browser. Sessions and Cookies are the suggested solution. You can verify it by going through a lot of SO questions asked before.

Comment: @KunalDethe You should copy-paste your comment to Answer, because it is :)

Comment: @tasmaniski, thanks for the suggestion. I have copied the comment as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems what you wish for is not possible as the added custom headers get discarded because the redirect is considered as a new request by the browser.

Sessions and Cookies are the suggested solution.

You can verify it by going through a lot of SO questions asked before.